# can i have an Extention method for a method?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to write code like this?

```
public void DoSomeOperation().Log()
{

}.Log()
```

Above call will execute Log() function while entering the DoSomeOperation method and while exiting the method. Can i do something like that? I know i can use AOP here but without using AOP, does .NET give this kind of luxary?

Comment: Extension methods are hooked up by the type-definition of a variable. Since your method returns void, and not a concrete type, it can't be done. Always remember to see Extension-methods as syntax sugar for writing static helper methods that take a variable as parameter.

Comment: Ok. If i return bool here, is it possible to do so?

Comment: sure, you can have an Extension method with the signature of *static bool MyExtensionMethod(this bool some_parameter_name)*

Comment: You can use Autofac's TypeInterceptors, or derive from ContextBoundObject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LogWrapper(DoSomeOperation);
LogWrapper(() => DoSomeOtherOperation(42));
LogWrapper(() => AndAnother("example"));

// ...

public static void LogWrapper(Action action)
{
    Log();
    action();
    Log();
}
```

Comment: goal here is to make the call to the Log() without writing inside method.

Comment: @Asdfg: It's not inside your existing method; the `LogWrapper` method takes an `Action` delegate as an argument. That delegate can execute whatever arbitrary code you like (for example, calls to your existing, unchanged methods).

Answer (score 3):

Am I missing something, or wouldn't it just look like this?

```
public void DoSomeOperation()
{
    Log();

    // Rest of method body

    Log();
}
```

If you mean to add the `Log()` calls to an existing `DoSomeOperation()` method, you could perhaps just override it like this if it's virtual:

```
public override void DoSomeOperation()
{
    Log();
    base.DoSomeOperation();
    Log();
}
```

Or better yet use a wrapper method and pass in a delegate of the respective method [as LukeH suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098420/can-i-have-an-extention-method-for-a-method/6098464#6098464).

As to actually decorating every method invocation in your class with `Log()` calls, I don't believe C# offers such a feature. Not as far as I know, anyway.

Comment: it certainly will but if i can write it differently then i dont have to add my Logging statements inside the method. Also if i can specify a common logging function at Class level then all the methods will execute it without me specifying it in each and every method.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. You'd have to write it like so:

```
public void DoSomeOperation()
{
    Log();

    // ....

    Log();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only recommend you [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) and the [logging aspect](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/5-Ways-That-Postsharp-Can-SOLIDify-Your-Code-Logging-and-Auditing.aspx).